# Use InteractionManager from redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

In a react-native app, I want to use [InteractionManager](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/interactionmanager) from [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga).

```
InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
  // ...long-running synchronous task...
});
```

Is it possible ? How to use it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions()` returns a promise, so you can use it inside a Saga with the `call` effect:

```
yield call(InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions)
```

Comment: I do not have any more the possibility to try it but if someone confirm it, I will accept this answer.

Comment: @JulienMalige confirmed. The solution works. Adamvert, thanx, bro